# Rental Dates -Each Quarter should be 90 Days but year end should be 365/366 days

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have multiple leases, where I have start date and expiry dates, I would like to get the quarterly dates between the start date and expiry date with the condition that each quarter (Q1, Q2, Q3) should be 90 days but Q4 should be 365 or 366 days from the start date.

I'm attaching a screenshot for two leases, is there any excel formula or VBA to get this desired result.

any help will be much appreciated.

[Quarterly Payment dates-90 days conditon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuPkO.png)
thanks
aleem

Comment: Your requirements seem odd. Q1 is January 1 through March 31, which does not contain exactly 90 days. Neither does April 1 through June 30. Using proper quarterly periods makes what you're asking totally unnecessary. Why are you over-complicating this?

Comment: Ken, Apologies if you have not understood properly, in my example 1. the start date of lease is 2nd Oct 2017 and the first quarter date is 90 days from 2nd Oct 2017 which is 31 Dec 2017, Similarly if you add 31 Dec 2017 with 90 days it will give 31st Mar 2018 and so on. Same logic applies to the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired results are perfect, still, I request to the excel gurus to see if any better approach is available

```
Sub qtrcalc()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim z As Integer
Dim ldate As Date
Dim x As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim Ydate As Date

StartDate = Range("c1")
EndDate = Range("c2")


z = DateDiff("q", StartDate, EndDate) '+ 1 ' for begining of the month date

ldate = DateAdd("d", 90, StartDate) 'for the end date based on freq

            Range("c27").Value = ldate

Range("c27").Value = StartDate


For x = 28 To 28 + z - 2

    Cells(x, 3).Value = DateAdd("d", 90, StartDate)

        Ydate = Range("c1").Value
        For k = 31 To 31 + z - 5 Step 4
        Cells(k, 3).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Ydate)
        Ydate = Cells(k, 3)
        Next k

    StartDate = Cells(x, 3)


Next x


End Sub
```